# Visual Studio 2010: Backslash or forwardslash (c++)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, include, static-libraries

In VS 2010 i want to add a macro in the property manager. Which slash should i use for that?

Example:

$(CPPLIB) = D:\CPPLib\ or D:\CPPLib (Backslash)
or 
$(CPPLIB) = D:/CPPLib/ or D:/CPPLib (Forwardslash)

The same question is for include and library directories in a project under C++->General->Additional Include directories or Linker->Addtional

What shall i use for it?

Do you use "/" or "\" ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use which-ever you want I think. Though if you use forward slash it might stick out like a sore thumb. :)

Comment: and do you add trailing slash to macros like MACRO: $(CPPLIB) = D:/CPPLIB/ or D:/CPPLIB - without trailing slash

Comment: But what is good for LINUX/WINDOWS compatible?

Comment: Does there even exist an MSBuild evaluator for Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should work equally well for local paths:  Windows will accept either path separator.

Comment: Thank you! At least i tried it out last night and got no errors while mixing.